# Magento 2: Add custom field to Admin Store edit

Tags: magento2, override-block

I am trying to add a custom field to Admin Store Edit

I have overridden the block function `_prepareStoreFieldset` locate in `vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/System/Store/Edit/Form/Website.php`

This is my `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website">
        <preference for="Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website" type="Vendor\Module\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then I created a file in `Vendor\Module\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form;

/**
 * Adminhtml store edit form for the website
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 */
class Website extends \Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory $groupFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $groupFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare website specific fieldset
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form
     * @return void
     */
    public function _prepareStoreFieldset(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form)
    {
        $fieldset = $form->getForm()->getElement('website_fieldset');

        $fieldset->addField(
            'website_type',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'website[type]',
                'label' => __('Type'),
                'value' => 1,
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => false
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

But it did not work. Anywhere I am wrong? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: where you create di.xml?

Comment: I created in etc/adminhtml

Comment: This is not your main issue, but you shouldn't add custom files in vendor, otherwise they will be erased the next time you will run composer. You need to override in one of your custom module out of vendor.

Comment: ah, I didn't add custom file in vendor, I created file in app/code/vendor/module, just describe which file I want to override

Answer (score 3):

Try the following way using event observer:

Step 1: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_store_edit_form_prepare_form">
        <observer name="vm_adminhtml_store_edit_form_prepare_form"
                  instance="VendorName/ModuleName\Observer\AdminhtmlStoreEditFormPrepareForm"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Step 2: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/AdminhtmlStoreEditFormPrepareForm.php

```
    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Store as StoreForm;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class AdminhtmlStoreEditFormPrepareForm implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * AdminhtmlStoreEditFormPrepareForm constructor.
     *
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this|void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof StoreForm) {
            $form = $block->getForm();
            $fieldset = $form->getElement('store_fieldset');
            $storeModel = $this->registry->registry('store_data');
            $fieldset->addField('website_type', 'text', array(
                'name'      => 'store[type]',
                'label'     => __('Type'),
                'value'     => $storeModel->getType(),
                'required'  => false,
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create override the things, then you need to write this into your `di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Backend\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website" type="Vendor\Module\Block\System\Store\Edit\Form\Website" /> 
</config>
```